# xjc errors out when using scd in binding customization

Tags: plugins, maven, jaxb

When customizing a binding using scd, non-Sun jaxb plugins are not recognized

For example, this does NOT work:

```
<jaxb:bindings
    scd="/~fpml:TradeHeader">
    <ext:interfaces>
        example.TradeHeaderDelegateInterface
    </ext:interfaces>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

However, this works:

```
<jaxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="../schemas/fpml-5-1/fpml-doc-5-1.xsd"
    node="/xsd:schema//xsd:complexType[@name='TradeHeader']">
    <ext:interfaces>
        example.TradeHeaderDelegateInterface
    </ext:interfaces>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

and, this works:

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    scd="/~fpml:CommodityMarketDisruption//fpml:marketDisruptionEvent">
    <jaxb:property name="marketDisruptionEvent"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

which makes me think that scd and third party plugins don't get along:

The error I get is:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/projects/domain-fpml-5-1/src/main/resources/xjb/fpml-5-1.xjb{40,19}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ext:interfaces'.
```

My .xjb file does declare the namespace for the "ext" prefix, so that's not the issue.

Has anyone worked with xjc plugins (e.g. the jaxb commons ones like Copyable etc.) and gotten it to work with scd based customization?

My xjc version is: 2.2.2 and I'm using the maven-jaxb2-plugin (version 0.8.0) plugin to generate bindings.

Thanks for any help,

aravind

Comment: I'm observing this issue as well. Annoying, because the SCD-based approach is clearly preferable (when it works, that is). Related: http://jira.highsource.org/browse/JIIB-47

Answer (score 1):

maven-jaxb22-plugin:jar:0.8.1:runtime, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.5-b10:runtime, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.5-b10:runtime] still exhibit this issue.

From looking at the xjc source code (some time ago) this is NOT an easy fix, because the customizations are not "imported" into the target xsd and the processing occurs in the context of the matched component.

This is the case with the Schema parser where by the schema is "imported" into the bindings context so all the namespaces are valid.

I have reverted all customizations back to schema style.  I remember this had painful implications when trying to do both wsdl and xsd in the same bindings file.